# If a date has passed

Tags: mysql, sql

Anyone know how to check if a date has gone by. I have a return date column in my database which is a future date and when this date has gone by I need to include this inside a trigger to alert the manager. I have tried this code but it is not working.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER date_expired BEFORE INSERT ON external_requests
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF return_date >= (return_date) Then 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' set message_text='This book has not been returned to the library';

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what your requirement is. Do you really want a trigger that prevents inserts with a date in the past? Or don't you rather want some process that looks at regular intervals at the existing records and sends an information when a date is reached?

Comment: I don't understand the point of any of this. When the manager wants to know which books are overdue, presumably they can just run a query.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `curdate()`?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER date_expired BEFORE INSERT ON external_requests
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF return_date >= curdate() Then 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
               set message_text='This book has not been returned to the library';
    end if;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Also he should use now() if return_date is a datetime field.

Comment: A standard conforming and more readable version would be `CURRENT_DATE` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto why do you care to use standard conforming `CURRENT_DATE` here.. Porting this trigger to a other database would require a complete rewrite annywhy..

Comment: @Elanochecer The return date column is a future date and cannot be a current date

Comment: @user11271599 well it's a future date when you store it... not always.